# react native webview ios white screen when app in background for a while

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I'm getting white screen with react native webview, when app in background for a while .

I've reading about that there are some people suggest to reload the webview after restoring the app from background but this solution is not convenient, what if I'm filling some form and minimized the app just for few seconds, I'll lose everything with reloading

I'm thinking if I can check how long app is in background before reloading the webview
any ideas ?

thanks